# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to create an array list of user input

Tags: java, arrays

I want to have the user assign strings to the 2 arrays. Then I want him to be able to type a number after the assignment to pull up the value assigned to  the string.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main (String[]args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String customerList[] = new String[2];

    customerList[1] = keyboard.nextLine();
    customerList[2] = keyboard.nextLine();


    System.out.println("Which array  value  would you like to see?");

    int listNum = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println(customerList[listNum]);
    }

}
```

Comment: So what's the exception you're getting?  `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: Yes, I resolved the issue. Did not even notice I put 1 instead of 0 to begin the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first value for an array is indexed at 0 not 1:

```
customerList[0] = keyboard.nextLine();
customerList[1] = keyboard.nextLine();
```

And here's a great tutorial for Java Arrays:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html